# Как сделать Rxjs interval в запросе

Tags: typescript, http, angular, rxjs

Service:

```
import {Injectable} from '@angular/core';
import {HttpClient, HttpHeaders} from '@angular/common/http';
import {Observable} from 'rxjs';


@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class UsersService {

  constructor(private httpClient: HttpClient, private cookieStorage: CookieStorageService) {
  }


  getUsersInfo(accountId: string, userId: string): Observable<any> {
    let contentHeader  = new HttpHeaders(
      {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        'Authorization': 'token'; }
    );
    return this.httpClient.get(`foo.com/users, {
      headers: contentHeader
    });
  } 
}
```

ts:

```
import {interval, of, Subscription, Observable} from 'rxjs';
      Message = null;

ngOnInit() {
      this.service.getUsersInfo(this.accountId, this.userId)
      .pipe(
        interval(1000), 
      ).subscribe((res) => {
        this.Message = res.body.message
        return;
      }),
}
```

Получаю ошибку: `Type 'Observable<number>' provides no match for the signature '(source: Observable<any>): Observable<{}>'`.

Comment: Что вы подразумеваете по интервалом. Сделать паузу (задержку) между началом запроса и получение ответа. Или по интервалу вызывать запрос, например раз в секунду?

Comment: Отправляю запрос -> получаю ответ, жду секунду и заново.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Создаем подписку через [interval](https://rxjs.dev/api/index/function/interval), а потом передаем в поток наш запрос в [switchMap()](https://rxjs.dev/api/index/function/switchMap)

```
import {interval, of, Subscription, Observable} from 'rxjs';

message = null;

ngOnInit() {
  interval(1000)
    .pipe(switchMap(() => this.service.getUsersInfo(this.accountId, this.userId)))
    .subscribe((res) => {
          this.message = res.body.message;
    })
}
```